# jersey with eclipse

Tags: java, jersey

I'm developing a server-side application with jersey.. the framework is good and I like it but I have a problem:

-the FIRST time that I request a page (for exmple http://:/testAPI)
I get this error

(note that I get this error only the first time that I write the url in the browser.. if I resent the request all go well ever..)

```
  n thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   org/codehaus/jackson/xc/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospector(MapperConfigurator.java:171)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospectors(MapperConfigurator.java:146)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._setAnnotations(MapperConfigurator.java:133)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator.getDefaultMapper(MapperConfigurator.java:70)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.locateMapper(JacksonJsonProvider.java:648)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.writeTo(JacksonJsonProvider.java:500)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.httpserver.HttpHandlerContainer.handle(HttpHandlerContainer.java:191)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:65)
at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:65)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:68)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:557)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:65)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:529)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:                         rg.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 20 more
```

can you help me?

thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the [optional Jackson XML Compatibility (XC) library](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload).

Comment: but i'm not using xml, only json..

I still tryied to download and add this http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksonxcjar.htm

but the error remains

Comment: i added xc but now the error is:

Webservice started http://10.23.2.127:8032/Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Comment: It doesn't matter if you are using XML, it is a dependency jackson requires.

The exception you are seeing could be caused by you downloading a version of the XC jar that is incompatible with the version of Jackson you are using. I'd find out what version of Jackson you are using and then download a compatible version of the XC jar from http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload